# IBM software architect, Eclipse error: "Java was started but returned exit code=-1"

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-rational

I'm trying to install IBM rational software architect 9.7, but i get the following error all time. It appeared during installation and does the same every time I run it.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRigo.jpg)
Here's the eclipse.ini file from the IBM source folder:

```
-vm  
E:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\jdk\jre\bin\javaw.exe  
-startup  
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar 
--launcher.library    
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834    
-install  
E:/Program Files/IBM/SDP  
-vmargs  
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=11001  
-Xquickstart  
-Xms512m  
-Xmx1536m  
-Xmnx64m  
-Xgcpolicy:gencon  
-Xscmx96m  
-Xshareclasses:name=IBMSDP_%u  
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M  
-Xcompressedrefs  
-Dcom.ibm.ws.management.event.max_polling_interval=1000  
-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true
```

I've reinstalled java jdk, eclipse and the IBM itself several times, this time on different disk E, instead of C, but still the same. Tried to install on ubuntu and it works normally. I've tried latest jdk 8u192 in both 32 and 64bit version, but nothing helps.

Comment: Weird. Try removing the properties related to memory usage. Or try higher values... Worst case, turn to ibm developer forums. In the end, this is a commercial product (you pay money for it, right) so talk to the people you paid for delivering a working product to you!

Comment: It's the trial version. I just need it for one month for a study project.

Comment: The VM must be specified before `-vmargs`, not at the beginning. Does moving the first two lines down directly before `-vmargs` solve your issue? If not, try to remove all lines after `-vmargs` except those that start with `-Xm` or `-D`.

Comment: Didn't work, still the same.

Comment: At least the error message cannot be the same. What do you get if you execute `"E:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\jdk\jre\bin\java.exe" -version` on the command line? Can folders and files be created in `E:\Program Files\IBM\SDP` without admin rights? What exactly did you install (please add the download links to your question)? Where did you get the incorrect `eclipse.ini` from and which lines did you change?